# How to set text box read only if it has value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to  to set text box  read only if it has value in view in MVC.

So I write

```
 <tr>
 @if (model.first_name != "" ) { 
   <td >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
            </td>
            <td >
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name)
                <span class="required">*</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
            </td>
@ else  
  <td >
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
            </td>
            <td >
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)
                <span class="required">*</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
            </td>
@}

            <td >
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
            </td>
            <td >
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)
                <span class="required">*</span>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

But is is not working..
How to slove it??
How can I do it??

Comment: Is it not compiling (missing brackets) or is there a separate issue? What *is* happening?

Answer (score 4):

You can modify your view model like the following

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  public string first_name { get; set; }

  public object first_name_attributes
  {
    get
    {
      return string.IsNullOrEmpty(first_name) ? null : new { @readonly = "readonly" };
    }
  }
}
```

In your UI, you can then add the object declaratively.

```
Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.first_name, first_name_attributes)
```

This results in a much simpler UI and the the view model has the benefit of being unit testable!

Answer (score 3):

You can make the field `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled="disabled"` A readonly field value will be submitted to the server while still being non-editable by the user.

Answer (score 1):

Create an if statement in razor and have a disabled = "disabled" on the input/editor that you want to disable.

```
@if
(model.first_name != null)
{

   <td >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
        </td>
        <td >
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.first_name)
            <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
        </td>
}
else
{
  <td >
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
        </td>
        <td >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" }))
            <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
        </td>

        <td >
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.first_name):
        </td>
        <td >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.first_name)
            <span class="required">*</span>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.first_name)
        </td>
    </tr>
```

}

Comment: While this will work, please refrain from putting `if` blocks like this in your views. It is much more expressive to let your view models do the work for you.

Comment: @jarrett what would be your solution then?

Comment: @JarrettMeyer thanks for the feedback. I agree with you. I just wanted to show user1348351 how to fix his code.